# How can i generate private key for firebase admin sdk?

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin, firebase-console

I am trying to create new private key for firebase admin sdk, but the button is not available. Can someone guide me on how can i achieve this?

[image]

Any solution appreciated!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After a lot of struggle. Finally, I found the solution. Just go to google cloud and click on the firebase-admin option and add your keys

https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/serviceaccounts

You can also check [this](https://youtu.be/cXOzbKDXTh0) video

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

*firebaser here*

The option to generate this key was accidentally removed from the Firebase console last Friday, as a new version of the console interpreted the HTML differently than in the past. We have a fix for this rolling out in production today.